# Understand differential inclusion in continuous-time fictitious play

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, game-theory, differential

I'm reading [this lecture slides](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-254-game-theory-with-engineering-applications-spring-2010/lecture-notes/MIT6_254S10_lec11.pdf) to understand the underlying theories of Fictitious play, but I get stuck when reading Page 21. Here's the snapshot of that page
[image]

where $BR_i$ is the best response of player $i$, $p_i$ is the average strategy of player $i$, $p_{-i}$ is the average strategy of players other than $i$, $\Sigma$ is the strategy space, and `u_{i}` is the utility function which player $i$ aims to maximize.

I don't understand why it uses the inclusion sign $\in$ in CTFP but uses the equality $=$ in perturbed CTFP. I'm aware of the existence of explanation--"Since $C_i$ is uniquely deﬁned, the perturbed CTFP is described by a differential equation rather than a differential inclusion."--but I don't know how to make sense of it. To me, the term `differential inclusion` is quite strange and I still cannot understand it even after reading the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_inclusion) and several other resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is a little bit confusing which might be the source of your problems.

The authors define $$BR_i(p^t_{-i}) = argmax_{\sigma_i \in \Sigma_i} u_i(\sigma_i, p^t_{-i})$$ which is not correct. It should be written as $$BR_i(p^t_{-i}) \in argmax_{\sigma_i \in \Sigma_i} u_i(\sigma_i, p^t_{-i})$$. (After all, given an opponent's strategy, you tend to have multiple strategy that is best response to it.)

In the second one, you have, $C_i(p^t_{-i}) = argmax_{\sigma_i \in \Sigma_i} u_i(\sigma_i, p^t_{-i}) - V_i(\sigma_i)$, which is correct. This is because $-V_i(\sigma_i)$ is strictly concave. $u_i(\sigma_i, p^t_{-i})$ is linear in its argument $\sigma_i$. You are maximizing a strictly concave function. This will always give you a single maximizer.

Does this help?

Comment: Definitely help a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, @Norman. I see that it introduced $V_i(\sigma_i)$ to get the differential equation. In other words, $V_i(\sigma_i)$ is used to differentiate different best response. But what property should $V_i(\sigma_i)$ have except convexity? Based on what does $V_i(\sigma_i)$ make the preference?